# Docker eclipse/che not work: "Error response from daemon: manifest for eclipse/che:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown" how to fix?

Tags: docker, eclipse-che

Docker Desktop latest version

[image]

log

```bash
D:\dockervy\pgadmin>docker run eclipse/che start
Unable to find image 'eclipse/che:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for eclipse/che:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.
See 'docker run --help'.

D:\dockervy\pgadmin>docker pull eclipse/che
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for eclipse/che:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

D:\dockervy\pgadmin>docker pull eclipse/che:latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for eclipse/che:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

D:\dockervy\pgadmin>docker pull eclipse/che
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for eclipse/che:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

D:\dockervy\pgadmin>
```

[image]

https://hub.docker.com/r/eclipse/che/

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Basically means there is no latest tag probably.
If you switch to **tags tab** or use this link https://hub.docker.com/r/eclipse/che/tags you will see list of available tags, pick one that is most suitable and copy the pull command.
Just tried this one and it worked:
`docker pull eclipse/che:7.0.0-RC-1.1`